# WebThread crashes on over-released CA object

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cordova

I have built an App in Swift but with Cordova which is Obj C. I also use crashlytics. I'm seeing a crash in about 10% of users, previously I experienced it a lot myself when using the debugger but since iOS 8.3 I don't, but that doesn't seem to have reduced the problem in the wild.

The crash is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS` in `CA::release_objects(X::List<void const*>*) + 32`, called when the autorelease pool is drained. The crash is always in the WebThread.

I can't seem to reproduce locally with Zombies profiling, so it is difficult to narrow down any further, but I can't see what would be causing this in my code. I do use Core Animation but only in swift, and this was happening before I added the CA code. I use `UIView` animations, but again it is all in Swift with Storyboards and I can't think where anything would be going wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you use some ads, like admob? I also have similar issue, and only webthread in my app is created by AdMob banner.